# Django ModelMultipleChoice validation error

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to send a dynamic amount of selections of checkboxes on obj.html to the /items function. I'm getting the error

```
"Select a valid choice. 1234 is not one of the available choices."
```

But you'll notice that I print the queryset of choices from #views.py, it outputs that 1234 is contained in the flat queryset, with quotes around it.

```
print(form.fields['choices'].queryset)
# Console output
['1234', '1243',...]
```

Why is 1234 not one of the available choices? I've tried putting quotes around the value attribute in the input form but it doesn't work. The items function stops because the data is not valid. How can I solve this?

```
# forms.py
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
  choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
  queryset = Sampledata.objects.none())

# views.py
def obj(request, object_id,):
    data = Sampledata.objects.filter(id=object_id)
    form = ItemForm()
    form.fields['choices'].queryset = list(data.values_list('value', flat=True))
    print(form.fields['choices'].queryset)
    return render(request, 'obj.html', {'data':data,'form':form})

def items(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
           ...

# obj.html
   <form action="/items" method="post">
   # Many of these spread out throughout the page
   {% for obj in data %}
   <input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="{{obj.value}}">
   {% endfor %}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Updated but still get the same error:

```
def items(request, object_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        data = Sampledata.objects.filter(id=object_id)
        form.fields['choices'].queryset = (data.values_list('value', flat=True))
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
```

Comment: But you modify it in `obj`, but process it in `items`. Those are two separate views and two separate instances of ItemForm.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So you're saying I need to add `form.fields['choices'].queryset = list(data.values_list('value', flat=True))` in `def items`?

Comment: Or better yet, make them one single view. Why are they separate? Also that code should really live in the form itself, in the `__init__` method; but you will still need to pass in the object_id, so still better to make it one single view. (And separately, why are you doing all that with `values_list`? The queryset attribute just needs to be a queryset.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I made them separate because obj.html is dependent on a previous form which is also dynamic. I see your point though and I'll reconsider doing it like that. The value that the user picks is one attribute out of many in `Object`, so I thought to use `values_list` in order to get the queryset of those values. Is this not how its done? I moved the queryset value over to items and I'm getting the same error